# Старт инфографики при открытии, а не при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, frontend

Есть js, он срабатывает при скроле. Мне срочно нужно исправить, чтоб он стартовал при открытии страницы. Плохо шарю js.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){var time=2;var lock=false;$(window).scroll(function(){var el=$('div[data-num]');var scrollTop=$(window).scrollTop();var windowHeight=$(window).height();var offset=el.offset();if(scrollTop<=offset.top&&(el.height()+offset.top)<(scrollTop+windowHeight)){if(!lock){$('div[data-num]').each(function(){var i=1;var that=$(this);var num=$(this).data('num'),step=1000*time/num,int=setInterval(function(){if(i<=num){that.children().children('.result-number').html(i)}else{clearInterval(int)}i++},step)})}lock=true}})});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание на var lock, возможно будет мешать, можете удалить, но на всякий случай я его оставил. Переменная возможно участвует в другом куске скрипта и важна.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var time=2;
  var lock=false;
  if(!lock){
   $('div[data-num]').each(function(){
    var i=1;
    var that=$(this);
    var num=$(this).data('num'),step=1000*time/num,int=setInterval(function(){
     if(i<=num){that.children().children('.result-number').html(i)}
     else
     {clearInterval(int)}i++},step)}
   )}
  lock=true
 })
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! То, что мне нужно.